# Filter the Reference Assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

We are the providing custom controls for all platforms in Visual Studio .Net. We are adding assemblies into ToolboxControlsInstaller and Register the assemblies in AssemblyFoldersEx under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework. When use the Add reference (to add assemblies C# projects) for Windows Phone Projects, it shows all platform assemblies from GAC like MVC, Windows and WPF. Is there any possible to filter assemblies and show only phone assemblies for Windows Phone Projects. Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance[image].

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) for Visual Studio!

It replaces the default "Add Reference" dialog with a better one, and on top, shows that it is filtering the references by platform!

Comment: Is there any other possibility to do this from registry itself instead of installing other tools? since we didn’t install this tool to our customer machines.

Comment: Productivity Power Tools does not play nicely with Resharper or Coderush due to major slowdowns in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight for WindowsPhone\v4.0\AssemblyFoldersEx

If we create a new Key under the above registry location then set the Assemblies location as default value. Then put what are the assemblies we want to add in Add Reference tab in that location. It will resolve this issue.